# Are the Lightning Data Service types for Aura Components and LWC component different?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service

Do we have different LDS for AURA and LWC components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, LDS services both Aura and LWS. It is actually written in the Aura runtime (at the time of this answer).